# Which algorithm should be used to solve this sorting exercise?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to solve the following problem,but I am stuck. The problem is as follows-

Suppose you are given an array of integers.You have to remove certain elements from the array so that the entire array is sorted in ascending order. Elements can't be repeated, so if any element is repeated in the array, it also should be removed. You have to find the minimum number of integers that needs to be removed from the array in order to sort it in ascending order.

I am posting a few test cases so that the question becomes clear:

1. Input

   1 1 2

   Output-1(since 1 is repeated and if removed, the array is sorted)

2.Input - 1 8 9 3 4 5

Output-2(since 8,9 if removed the array is sorted and it is also the minimum number required)

3. Input- 1 7 8 9 3

   Output - 1(only 3 should be removed)

   My approach was to move through the array and if the previous number is bigger than the current number, then the previous number should be removed. By this approach, 1 and 2 will get solved, but case 3 will output 3 for this approach.

   How should I solve this problem? Is there any specific algorithm that might be helpful?

Comment: First determine each number's relation to the one before it. Say in example 3, it would be: larger, larger, larger, smaller. Once you have this information, you decide whether there are more numbers that are smaller than the previous one, or more that are bigger. Whichever case appears the least amount of times (in this example, it's "smaller"), you remove the numbers that correspond to that kind of case (number 3 in this example). So basically whichever tendency the set follows more, that's the one you leave, and you remove anything that doesn't follow that. I might be wrong though...

Comment: it's the longest increasing subsequence problem, not sorting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that we have thrown away some numbers so that the remaining array is sorted. What does the remaining numbers form in the initial array? An increasing subsequence. We want to throw away as few numbers as we can, or, put it another way, keep as many numbers as possible. Thus, we need to find the longest increasing subsequence in the given array.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me in solving the problem